# Process java still being killed

Tags: nohup

I need to run a java program on my university servers. I'm remotely logging in through their servers via ssh

So I used nohup like so:

```
nohup java -jar project.jar &
```

However when I logout and close the terminal then log back into the server my process is missing/got killed off.

Comment: Try redirecting `stdout` and `stderr` to some files - your process may be killed by signal other than SIGHUP, when trying to write to a closed terminal `stdout`/`stderr`. E.g. add `>/dev/null 2>&1` to your command before `&` job sign.

Comment: @Bob shouldn't be necessary with `nohup` - most implementations will do this by default although it may be necessary to redirect `stdin` eg `</dev/null`.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

`nohup` only make program immune to `SIGHUP` and `SIGQUIT` signal. Modern shell maybe send other signals when you logout from your session, so there is no guarantee that your program is not killed, even running under `nohup`.

The better solution is using `tmux` or `screen`, or if you use `bash`, you can try:

```
$ java -jar project.jar &
$ disown
```

Comment: If you use `disown`, you need to redirect manually, eg add `</dev/null &>/dev/null`

Comment: @Graeme: I think if we don't work with the shell anymore (just run command and exit), there is no need to redirecting.

Comment: Try `ssh localhost 'sleep 10m & disown'`. `bash` won't exit.

Comment: Ok it seems to be `ssh` that doesn't exit if there are programs connected to the terminal. However, the above is fine if you run interactively.

Comment: The Linux (GNU coreutils and busybox) and BSD implementations of `nohup` do not make the command immune to `SIGQUIT`, but only to `SIGHUP`. That would be explicitly against the [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/nohup.html#tag_20_87_09) and AFAIK may only happen on (some versions of?) Solaris.

Answer (score 13):

Yet another option in place of the (chronically dysfunctional) `nohup`:

```
setsid java -jar project.jar </dev/zero &>/dev/null &
```

This effectively "daemonizes" the process.  It is now owned by init, so will never get HUP'd, its I/O streams are safe, and it has been forked into the background.

See `man setsid` for more information.  Unlike `screen` or `tmux`, this is not a program which claims ownership and continues to run.  It simply starts a program in its own [process group](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Process_group).

Comment: Why is nohup dysfunctional?

Comment: @cpugeniusmv I'm sure it's good for something, however, I did not find it reliable for a purpose it is often recommended for, logging in somewhere, starting a process, and logging out (much like the OP).  I guess it could have been misuse, and perhaps `setsid` is a little more idiot proof this way.  It skips a step implied by nohup (having the process re-parented by init as an orphan).  `nohup` would be more flexible if you potentially want to foreground the job later.

Comment: @TAFKA'goldilocks' I think the problem is in handling stdin, stdout and stderr, which is not really (but partly(!)) handled by nohup. Nohup does it's main job pretty well, shielding the process from SIGHUP. But there are lots of things that can go wrong with the streams - or, much worse, go wrong sometimes, depending on buffer sizes. I'd say, not nohup is wrong, but the expectation what nohup does.

Comment: Why is the `</dev/zero &>/dev/null` part necessary?

Comment: It completes the detachment of the process from the parent context, which is, eg., `ssh` or a (pseudo) tty (or a pseudo tty in ssh).  Those things are connected by the process's input and output streams; if you let this run in the foreground, its output would go to the console, and it would also have an input stream coming from the console -- connections that may now be abruptly broken (this is why `nohup` prevents the SIGHUP, "hang up signal", that happens when the parent process exits).  I'm not completely sure my manual redirects are really necessary with `setsid` (which is....

Comment: ....derived from [the POSIX  C function of the same name](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/functions/setsid.html)).  Probably it is a bit paranoid but I have not found anything explicit stated one way or the other about it.

Answer (score 3):

Another idea would be to use the screen command. It is possible to start a program withhin screen, detach and logout. Afterwards you can login and attach to the running screen session.

Tutorial: http://www.rackaid.com/blog/linux-screen-tutorial-and-how-to/

Answer (score -2):

Try running your nohup with STDOUT and STDERR redirect to null:

```
nohup java -jar project.jar 2>&1 &
```

Comment: You're only redirecting stderr to stdout, which doesn't change anything about how nohup operates (it redirects both to `nohup.out`).

Comment: -1, I think you meant `nohup java -jar project.jar 2>/dev/null &` but you obviously don't know what you are doing. Even better, also feed `stdin` `/dev/null`.

Comment: @PlasmaPower here you have your +1. Have a nice day :)